# Simple Question on Triangles...

Tags: geometry, triangles

What times the sum of the squares of the sides of a triangle is equal to the sum of the squares of the medians of the triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\Large 2\cdot m_a^2+\frac{a^2}{2}=b^2+c^2$

$\Large 2\cdot m_b^2+\frac{b^2}{2}=c^2+a^2$

$\Large 2\cdot m_c^2+\frac{c^2}{2}=a^2+b^2$

Comment: I'm just in School...and I have never seen this Equation....SO could you please give a simpler HINT....

Comment: Wait....I think I'm getting it

Comment: It can be obtained from Apollonius' theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27_theorem

Comment: ...or Stewart's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart's_theorem whatever takes your fancy.

Comment: Those Va^2 and similar one are representing MEDIANS right..??

Comment: Yes, $m_i$ or $V_i$ represents the median.

Comment: Multiplying each equation by two and adding them all....We get... 2 (Va^2 + Vb^2 + Vc^2) = 5 (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)  Right...???? But I think I have done a mistake somewhere...

Comment: Sorry I have misguided you a bit there! I have edited my answer. You should get $4(m_a^2+m_b^2+m_c^2)=3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)$ at the end.

Comment: But I am getting something different that is  4(m2a+m2b+m2c)=5(a2+b2+c2)   Now what is my mistake...please..

Comment: $4m_a^2=2b^2+2c^2-a^2$ You have MINUS $a^2$, not plus. That is your mistake.

Comment: Oh yeah..Thanks I can be so silly sometimes....!!

Comment: We're all silly sometimes :)

Comment: How can we input Math Equations and Symbols like you did in your answers and comments?

Comment: You should put your equations between dollar signs: `$x^2=1$`

Comment: Here is a basic tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference